# Model Binding in ASP.NET Web Forms with Collections

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, model-binding

I'm having some trouble model binding my model with a form view server control. Basically I have a simple model with a "Dim Questions as list(of QuestionModel)" that containsQuestionModel contains 2 properties {.QuestionType, .AnswerValue}. When I try to "Text=<%# BindItem.Questions.Find(Function(question) question.QuestionType = "SomeType").AnswerValue %>" on the formview, I get the error "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code".

```
Public Class Form
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property Phone As String
    Public Property Questions As New List(Of QuestionModel)

    Public Sub New()
        Questions.AddQuestion("Question1")
        Questions.AddQuestion("Question2")
        Questions.AddQuestion("Question3")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class QuestionModel
    Public Property QuestionType As String
    Public Property AnswerValue As String
End Class

<Extension()>
Public Sub AddQuestion(ByRef Questions As List(Of QuestionModel), QuestionType As String, Optional AnswerValue As String = "")
    Dim Question As New QuestionModel With {.QuestionType = QuestionType, .AnswerValue = AnswerValue}
    Questions.AddQuestion(Question)
End Sub

<asp:FormView ID="fvRegistration" runat="server" ItemType="Form" DataKeyNames="FormID" SelectMethod="fvRegistration_GetItem" UpdateMethod="fvRegistration_UpdateItem" InsertMethod="fvRegistration_InsertItem">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.FirstName %>' />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.LastName %>' />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.Phone %>' />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# BindItem.Email %>' />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuestion1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Item.Questions.Find(Function(question) question.QuestionType = "Question1").AnswerValue %>'>
            <%--List Item Answers--%>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuestion2" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Item.Questions.Find(Function(question) question.QuestionType = "Question2").AnswerValue %>'>
            <%--List Item Answers--%>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuestion3" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Item.Questions.Find(Function(question) question.QuestionType = "Question3").AnswerValue %>'>
            <%--List Item Answers--%>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Any help would be great! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show us [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just made an edit with code.